# MIPS Assembler string compare 'method' and moving strings

Tags: string, assembly, compare, mips, move

I'm facing a task of comparing multiple strings with each other (including ones from user input). Solution I've been thinking about would be to create a label that compares two strings and in the $s0 register sets 1 if the strings are equal and 0 if they're not. Then the program jumps to the label which address is stored in the $a2 register.

The problem I have is how to 'prepare' the strings I'd like to compare. I've thought of two possibilities (none of which I'm able to implement):

- setting labeled in the .data segment two strings to the considered strings before jumping to 'compare:' label (the problem lies in setting labeled string into another labeled string)

  ```
  .data
      string1: .asciiz
      string2: .asciiz

  ...
  setting string1 to another labeled string (move label, label doesn't exist) 
  ...

  # a2 - finish label, $s0 - (1 - equal, 0 - not equal)
  compare:
      la $s0, 0
      c_for:
          lb $s6, string1($s0)
          lb $s7, string2($s0)
          bne $s6, $s7, notequal
          beq $s7, '\n', equal
          addi $s0, $s0, 1
          j c_for
      equal:
          la $s0, 1
          j finish
      notequal:
          la $s0, 0
      finish:
          jr $a2
  ```
- storing appropriate string labels in $a0 and $a1 addresses and acquiring single characters via those addresses

  ```
  ...
  # a0 - string 1, a1 - string 2, a2 - label finish, $s0 - (1 - equal, 0 - not equal)
  compare:
      la $s0, 0
      c_for:
          lb $s6, ($a0)($s0) # such lines don't work but they resemble
          lb $s7, ($a1)($s0) # what I've been trying to achieve
          bne $s6, $s7, notequal
          beq $s7, '\n', equal
          addi $s0, $s0, 1
          j c_for
      equal:
          la $s0, 1
          j finish
      notequal:
          la $s0, 0
      finish:
          jr $a2
  ```

The main problem definetely lies in my understanding of MIPS and assembler in general so any suggestions on solving this problem or understanding some principles of working with labeled strings would be welcome.

Comment: You can't index by two registers, but you can do the addition yourself before you index. E.g. instead of `lb $s6, ($a0)($s0)` you can do `addu $s6, $a0, $s0; lb $s6, ($s6)`

Comment: This solution does the job just as intended! Thanks a lot for a quick response!